# C2065 Errors on all my for loops

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, undeclared-identifier

When I try to compile my code in Visual Studio, I am getting C2065 Errors on every for loop, like this one:

```
int i;
    for (i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); ++i)
    {
        printf(STATISTICS_TABLE_LINE, PQgetvalue(res,i,0), PQgetvalue(res,i,1),
                PQgetvalue(res,i,2), PQgetvalue(res,i,3), PQgetvalue(res,i,4));
    }
```

The errors say:
`error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier`

As you can see, I **am** declaring the identifier `i`, but I am still getting this error.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure that exact same shown code is giving error?

Comment: @Dayalrai yes, 100% sure

Comment: are you getting any errors prior to that error? C89, which VS supports only, disallows mixing declarations and code.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: 2010, but the project was built with 08

Answer (score 1):

Visual C does not support C99 and do not allow mix type declarations. That's the reason behind this. Now try to declare `i` in the beginning of your program (just C89 style) and you will get rid off from this error.